# Unable to view Taxonomy term page: Access denied

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I am unable to view/see any Taxonomy term page in the front (Access denied).

I can edit Taxonomy in the admin backend.

**Example:**

http://localhost/{Taxonomy-group}/car

**Result:**

Page "Access denied - You are not authorized to access this page."

**Setup**

Alias URL (Taxonomy term paths)

Default path pattern (applies to all vocabularies with blank patterns below) 
`[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]`

**Tried but didn't work**

- Clear cache
- Rebuild permissions
- Update alias

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Access Denied Backtrace](https://www.drupal.org/project/adb) module.

Comment: Node access denied :There are not explicit access denied for this user     Here what i have ( image ) : http://i.share.pho.to/46e6961f_o.png         not super clear :(

Comment: that link is 404 for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering a similar issue on a localized site. The ADB module records an "Access Denied" occurence, but gives bo backtrace.

Workaround in my case: Overwrite the taxonomy term display with a view. It's not what I want, but I couldn't resolve the issue otherwise.